# Errors Compiling xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, wso2-iot

I am trying to building the iOS Agent application  for WSO2 emm on xCode 6.1
. I have got everything else working perfectly except the app compile. The instructions [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/iOS+Client+Configurations) are pretty non specific and don't even mention if your server url is the full url or just the ip.

https://ipetc/emm or if its just your ip address / domain.

The error that I get when compiling is not do with this but I get.

Unfefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$ApiResponse", referenced from: objc-class-ref in ApiResponseTest.o

I assumed that the valid build arch was wrong but it doesn't include any mention of x86_64 in their downloaded xcode project

Any help is appreciated in this final step.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add architecture Arm64 to your project. EMM agent is bit old and it does not support this architecture in the release version.